# What are named arguments compiled equivalents in JS?

Tags: dart

If I say something like

```
void simple({foo: true, bar: false}){
  print('$foo $bar');
}
```

Does it compile down to

```
function simple(foo, bar) ...
```

or does it turn the named arguments so it just accepts an 1 object as an argument containing object.foo and object.bar. I looked at the dart.js it generated but it looks like it's compiling the AST of the program from the javascript which is slightly insane to me.

Comment: What do you mean by insane? Its not supposed to be readable JavaScript. There are a lot of generalizations/optimizations going on. The method, function might even be inlined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, i have found that, as say [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer), a lot of optimization are done.

But, due to this optimization, the compiler avoid (as i see in my experimentation) passing object when it can. I think is for performance but i'm not sure

So in most of the time, Named argment are passed directly, and resolved during the compilation.

To test this, i have write a dummy code :

***dummy.dart***

```
import 'dart:math';

double calcFunc({int a, int b}) {
  return (a * b / (a+b)) * (new Random().nextInt(100)) ;
}

String myFunc({int a: 0, int b: 0}) {
  return "Numbers : ${a + calcFunc(a: a, b : b) * (new Random().nextInt(100))}";
}

void main() {
  print("Func call: ${myFunc(a: 42, b: 24)}");
  print("Func 2nd call: ${myFunc(a: 21)}");
}
```

and the result JS for the code (without all the thing generated)

***dummy.dart.js***

```
["", "main.dart", , F, {
  "^": "",
  myFunc: function(a, b) {
    var t1 = C.C__JSRandom.nextInt$1(100);
    return "Numbers : " + (a + a * b / (a + b) * t1 * C.C__JSRandom.nextInt$1(100));
  },
  main: function() {
    P.print("Func call: " + F.myFunc(42, 24));
    P.print("Func 2nd call: " + F.myFunc(21, 0));
  }
},
1],
]);
```

as you can this here, no object are passed in parameter, but they are directly replaced.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder now if class objects passed to functions are also broken down into single arguments. That would be ideal as I've always wanted something like a struct in javascript instead of accessing things by array offset when I need a vector.